# Getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." for my JS AJAX instead of "404: File Not Found"

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, .htaccess, server

I've made my website with two AJAX functions. One AJAX is essentially automatically inserting the top part of the page (which includes the static logo and the nav), and is called on `window.onload`. However, I have another AJAX that is called as soon as the page loads (no event is needed). This AJAX basically adds news feed to the website. It first checks for files in numerical order (1.html, 2.html...) until it reaches one that does not exist. The `.status` is supposed to change to `404` but it is just staying the same and is somehow giving me that "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error in the console. It works fine when I run in locally, but not with the free web hosting service (000webhost.com). The browser console is just returning this stupid error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://error404.000webhost.com/?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mywebsite.webuv.com' is therefore not allowed access
```

I even added the following to my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|js|json|html|css)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

But it is not working. The AJAX is not calling anywhere outside the website. Everything is done locally, which makes it even more confusing. Any help will be most appreciated.

I suspect that the server is not responding with a `.status = 404` for some reason...

Comment: Looks like whatever you're requesting is redirecting to a 404 page (`http://error404.000webhost.com/?`) that is outside your domain

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my server. When the file does not exist, it still keeps it in the `.status = 200` position and loads its own html file to the viewers (with sometimes explicit ads). The simplest way to solve this is to enter in your own custom files. To do so, create a PHP file with the following code:

```
<?php 

$status = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']; 
$codes = array( 
    403 => array('403 Forbidden', 'The server has refused to fulfill your request.'), 
    404 => array('404 Not Found', 'The document/file requested was not found.'), 
    405 => array('405 Method Not Allowed', 'The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the specified resource.'), 
    408 => array('408 Request Timeout', 'Your browser failed to sent a request in the time allowed by the server.'), 
    500 => array('500 Internal Server Error', 'The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.'), 
    502 => array('502 Bad Gateway', 'The server received an invalid response from the upstream server while trying to fulfill the request.'), 
    504 => array('504 Gateway Timeout', 'The upstream server failed to send a request in the time allowed by the server.') 
    ); 

$title = $codes[$status][0]; 
$message = $codes[$status][1]; 
if ($title == false || strlen($status) != 3) { 
    $message = 'Please supply a valid status code.'; 
} 

echo '<p><h1>' . $title . '</h1></p>' .  
     '<p>' . $message . '</p>';  

?>
```

Then save the file as `error.php` in the `public_html` folder. Open the `.htaccess` file in the `public_html` and add the following (May be erase the junk if you don't have your custom code there):

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```

Save it and upload both the files to the server (override any old ones if necessary).

This should override any server-set error pages and give you 'clean' ones. This means that when you call `.status` in AJAX JavaScript, you will get the proper response.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use local AJAX to retrieve external xml/json etc because your browser blocks this as it is a security risk.

To get around this there are a few methods, but the one I have used in the past is by using YQL (Yahoo query language) which acts as a middle man for AJAX requests.

You can read into YQL [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) and it is very simple to use.